# What physical resources will I need for web application built on java + tomcat + mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, server, hosting

I want to create dynamic website using java + tomcat + mysql. I want to buy some space on linode.com or digitalocean but I want to know what resources will application need to run normal way ( I am not expecting many users at all, 2-5 at the same time maximum).

Also I do not know which linux distro should I use to minimize cost.

Answer (score 1):

RAM:

for the system like Ubuntu you need 512Mo

for Tomcat you need 256Mo--->512Mo  (small applications),

for Mysql you need 256Mo,

and if you use Plesk you will need 512Mo

ROM:

also it depends on your application and your database

I'm using a 2 GB RAM vps to host one java application for dialysis center, 2 wordpress website , plesk and mysql